# Class and Interface comparing c#

Tags: c#, class, sorting, interface, compare

I want to sort the list of classes and interfaces. So my logic is

- if the class is not implemented interface it's higher than the interface, otherwise, it's lower

I am using the IComparer interface to sort my list. My model looks like this:

[image: Model]

My Comparer class (if returns 1 it means y>x, 0 is x==y -1 is x>y):

```
public class SortedTypeComparer : IComparer<Type>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Compares types
    /// </summary>
    public int Compare(Type x, Type y)
    {
        public int Compare(Type x, Type y)
    {
        if (y.IsAssignableFrom(x))
        {
            return 1; 
        }
        else if (x.IsAssignableFrom(y))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (!y.IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAssignableFrom(y) && x.IsInterface && y.IsClass)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (!y.IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAssignableFrom(y) && x.IsClass && y.IsInterface)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I am expecting when I sort the list it should be:

```
IAnimal
IRunnable
Animal
ICat
Cat
```

Or:

```
IRunnable
IAnimal
Animal
ICat
Cat
```

Because IRunnable and IAnimal are 'equal'. Here is my usage:

```
     var list = new List<Type>();
        list.Add(typeof(IAnimal));
        list.Add(typeof(IRunnable));
        list.Add(typeof(ICat));
        list.Add(typeof(Animal));
        list.Add(typeof(Cat));
        list.Sort(new SortedTypeComparer());
```

In this case, it is working as expected. But when I change the order of adding to list for example(put IRunnable to the end):

```
    var list = new List<Type>();
        list.Add(typeof(IAnimal));
        list.Add(typeof(ICat));
        list.Add(typeof(Animal));
        list.Add(typeof(Cat));
        list.Add(typeof(IRunnable));
        list.Sort(new SortedTypeComparer());
```

The order is

```
IAnimal
Animal
ICat
IRunnable
Cat
```

It is not my expectation because of IRunnable>Animal. It seems when it compare Animal and ICat Animal is higher, then when it compares ICat and IRunnable it's saying "ICat == IRunnable, so Animal should be > IRunnable". How can I write the logic in the Compare method to sort my list as expected?

Comment: Unrelated: `else if (!y.IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAssignableFrom(y) && x.IsInterface && y.IsClass)` - the first two seem redundand to me. They have already been checked.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint and note down with what types the comparer gets called and what the results are respective? Or have that logged out...

Comment: *My Comparer class (if returns 1 it means y>x, 0 is x==y -1 is x>y):* That is the opposite of the framework's convention. `ComparTo(x, y)` should return `1` when `x` is larger than `y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe answer of @JonasH more correct, but I did by fixing My comparer class. I added the following condition in my method and it is correct for most scenarios:

```
public class SortedTypeComparer : IComparer<Type>
{
    public List<Type> AllTypes { get; set; }

    public SortedTypeComparer(List<Type> types)
    {
        AllTypes = types;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compares types
    /// </summary>
    public int Compare(Type x, Type y)
    {
        var result = CompareIsHigherOrLower(x, y);
        if (result == 0)
        {
            var subEntitiesOfX = AllTypes.Where(a => x.IsAssignableFrom(a) && a != x);
            foreach (var subTypeOfX in subEntitiesOfX)
            {
                result = CompareIsHigherOrLower(subTypeOfX, y);
                if (result == -1)
                {
                    return -1;//It means SubEntity of X is higher then Y and X should be > Y
                }
            }

            var subEntitiesOfY = AllTypes.Where(a => y.IsAssignableFrom(a) && a != y);
            foreach (var subType in subEntitiesOfY)
            {
                result = CompareIsHigherOrLower(subType, x);
                if (result == -1)
                {
                    return 1;//It means SubEntity of Y is higher then X and Y should be > X
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    int CompareIsHigherOrLower(Type x, Type y)
    {
        if (y.IsAssignableFrom(x))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (x.IsAssignableFrom(y))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (!y.IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAssignableFrom(y) && x.IsInterface && y.IsClass)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (!y.IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAssignableFrom(y) && x.IsClass && y.IsInterface)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this is possible with a IComparer. From [CompareTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1.compareto?view=netcore-3.1#System_IComparable_1_CompareTo__0_)

> - For objects A, B, and C, the following must be true:
> - If A.CompareTo(B) returns zero and B.CompareTo(C) returns zero, then A.CompareTo(C) is required to return zero.

So if A inherits from C and B does not inherit anything, then according to your rules compareTo should return:

- A.CompareTo(B) -> 0
- B.CompareTo(C) -> 0
- A.CompareTo(C) -> 1

This violates the requirements of CompareTo.

An alternative would be to build an [Directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) of the hierarchy. Then you should be able to use [Topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) to sort the graph.